# Mustache partials and code reuse

Tags: php, templates, mustache

I'm getting the hang of mustache for a project I've started during the weekend.

I'm using the PHP implementation. I have, however a couple of inquiries as I'm not used to the system.

How do you handle template inheritance, or reuse?
I know of partials, but how should I use them? I'm doing something like this, ala include:

top.mustache:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='es'>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
     <header><h1><a href="/">Top</a></h1>
     </header>
     <section>
```

bottom.mustache:

```
        </section>
        <footer><a href="http://potajecreativo.com/">potaje</a></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

And a view to render this template:

```
{{>top}}
<form action="/album/" method="post">
    <p><label for="name">Name</label> <input type="text" name="name" value=""/></p>
    <p><label for="description">Description</label> <textarea name="description" rows="8" cols="40"></textarea></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Save" /></p>
</form>
{{>bottom }}
```

Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ynkr's answer is right for older versions, but I just upgraded to version 2.4.1 and there your approach should work if you're using the filesystemloader.

See https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/wiki/Template-Loading#partials-loading for details.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example of how the php implementation of Mustache works. Of note is that Mustache.php will **not** expand the included partials/templates, so you have to hand them to mustache as seen below. This example was pieced together on an older cakephp framework.

```
<?
  # php cannot recognize multiple acceptable file extensions for partials,
  # so toggle it to mustache's extension
  $this->ext = '.mustache';

  # Mustache says it's logic-less, but that's not exactly true.
  # Render out the basic header which calls the logo partial and has
  # a {{# logged_in? }} condition which dictates which user box we
  # show. Thus, we need to render out the html for both the logged in
  # and logged out user boxes
  $basic_header_html = $this->renderElement('basic_header');
  $logo       = $this->renderElement('shared/logo');
  $logged_in  = $this->renderElement('shared/logged_in_user_box');
  $logged_out = $this->renderElement('shared/logged_out_user_box');

  $m = new Mustache($basic_header_html,                    
                    array('logged_in?' => !empty($this->Auth->userData),
                          'cache_buster' => time(),
                          'display_name' => 'StackOverflow Customer'),
                    array('shared/logo' => $logo,
                          'shared/logged_in_user_box' => $logged_in,
                          'shared/logged_out_user_box' => $logged_out));
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Mustache Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <?= $m->render(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**basic_header.mustache**

```
<div id="header" class="basic">
  {{> shared/logo }}

  {{# logged_in? }}
    {{> shared/logged_in_user_box }}
  {{/ logged_in? }}

  {{^ logged_in? }}
    {{> shared/logged_out_user_box }}
  {{/ logged_in? }}
</div>
```

**shared/logo.mustache**

```
<a class="logo" href="/foo/bar"><img alt="" src="/images/logo.png?{{ cache_buster }}" /></a>
```

**shared/logged_in_user_box.mustache**

```
Hello {{display_name}}, you are logged in.
```

**shared/logged_out_user_box.mustache**

```
Hello. You are not logged in.
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're using the Cake framework in your example here, though nothing in the question or your answer alludes to that. You might want to clarify that in your answer to make it less confusing.